# Where can the Raco Pkgs library "table-editor" be downloaded?

Tags: racket, package

I'm attempting to install [this library](https://github.com/kugelblitz/spreadsheet-editor/tree/master) for Racket, which depends on a library called `table-editor`. Helpfully, there is a comment in the source:

```
;; raco pkg install table-panel
```

Unfortunately, that package doesn't seem to exist. Google is not returning helpful results. Does anybody know where to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the table-panel package at PLaneT.

http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/williams/table-panel.plt/1/2/planet-docs/table-panel/index.html